# Recommendations for a fre OSM based walking tour mobile app?

Tags: software-recommendations, mobile, walk

I am working with a small municipality with a very small (read:no) budget.  They would like to build a walking tour for mobile use based around natural features, and some history but mostly nature walks.

I have been looking around at the array of services and approaches to doing this (online serving of data vs. download in advance, media rich vs. just text, etc.) and so far have not found "the one".

I am hoping some folks here have had some experience building walking tours from easy-to-approach apps or services, as opposed to having an ArcGIS Online account, or building my own city-specific app which seems to be the way a lot of places have gone.

The lo-fi approach I want is something where I can upload a line feature for the route and point feature class for the stops, as KML or shapefile, and have that information overlaid on Open Street Maps for navigation.  The user would navigate to the points and tap the marker to read the text about the area.  Even better would be a location-aware app that allows multimedia and when the user walks within a proximity of the point, it notifies them that there is text/audio/images available to view.

Any recommendations for accomplishing this?  There seem to be a lot of options, so looking for simple workflow, and not really wanting to start downloading a myriad of apps to try them all out.

Comment: I think the site for software recommendations is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I had no idea that stack exchange even existed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Voicemap (https://voicemap.me/). This is a platform designed for exactly your use case. It allow writers to create and upload location-aware tours that can be consumed by anyone with the free app. You can charge for the tours per download, in which case you split the proceeds, but you set the price and so you can create free ones.

They do have a fairly high standard of quality. I believe they require the audio to be semi-professionally recorded and the transcript edited. However it is possible to use Voicemap to achieve exactly what you want without spending a cent. I don't know what maps they use to power the service, and I'm not sure if they allow media other than audio. So if these points are non negotiable that isthe only difficulty, but they are a small Cape Town and Singapore based start up who I am sure will be able to help you and answer any questions.